# ReactJS passing Stateful variables to child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a Login component which takes in username and password, and passes those values to the parent component using setState functions. I am getting an error which says

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Login (at App.js:35)
    in component (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Here is my Login component code that is causing the issue:

```
export default function Login (props) {

        const configs = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: username,
            }) 
        }
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/blades_login', configs)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.password)

        if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, data['password']) == true) {
            props.setLoggedIn(true)
            props.setUser(username)
            setResponse(true)
        }

        ...
}
```

Here are my Stateful variables and their corresponding routes:

```
export default function App() {

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

...

<Route exact path="/blades/login" component = {(props) =>  <Login {...props} setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setUser={setUser}/>}/>

...
}
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You're trying update state on an unmounted component, probably because you're routing to Login but then updating state on App afterwards

Comment: shouldn't you use that code in useEffect? (in Login component)

Answer (score 0):

```
    export default function App() {

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

const handleLogin = (val) => setLoggedIn(val)
const handleUser = (val) => setUser(val)


<Route exact path="/blades/login" component = {(props) =>  <Login {...props} setLoggedIn={handleLogin} setUser={handleUser}/>}/>

...
}
```

You're trying update state on an unmounted component. Passing a func over will do the trick